# How to modify wrong time zone in a Date object?

Tags: date-and-time

How can one modify the wrong time zone in a DateObject, without a conversion? Can one manipulate the TimeZone directly without having the numerical value of the time changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do1 = DateObject[3155673600]
```

[image]

```
do1 /. (TimeZone -> _) :> (TimeZone -> 12)
```

[image]

Observe that **GMT-8** has become **GMT+12**.  I believe this is what you want?

A different effect:

```
DateObject[do1, TimeZone -> 12]
```

[image]

**00:00:00** has become **20:00:00** here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Your first suggestion does the job - excellent!

Comment: @hippo3773 I am glad I could help.  Since you say this is exactly what you were looking for please consider [Accepting this answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428)