# Set hour of DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

Say I have a date object `date = DateObject[{2016, 7, 17, 0, 0}]`, how do I later change the hour of that date object, without needing to know the value it currently has?

I'm searching for something like `date /. Hour -> 18`, but can't find it in the documentation, just that

> DateObject allows addition and subtraction of time quantities.

**[Edit]** [How to modify wrong time zone in a Date object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105554/how-to-modify-wrong-time-zone-in-a-date-object) is related, but I already tried `date /. (Hour -> _) :> (Hour -> 18)` and that didn't work.

Comment: Related: [(105554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105554/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had seen that question already, but thanks - edited this question

Comment: FYI, my "Related" links are usually less about answering the question which they are under and more about site organization with the goal of helping people who later find your but need something just a bit different.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I understand, that is why I had edited the question to include the reference, hope that was right.

Comment: Perfectly fine, I just want to make sure you don't take my "Related" comment as somehow dismissive.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course not, you're only trying to help!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, does SE offer a programmatic way to display Related links? .. I find even the basic search lame, eg Q's & A's shuffled haphazardly.

Comment: @alancalvitti I am not sure what you mean.  Links appear in the **Linked** sidebar to the right.  If you want some kind of graph view I am not aware of any, but I suppose someone on this site could cook one up.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, right, I was thinking like a graph view showing how the Related (and their links etc) interrelate.

Comment: @alancalvitti That sounds like a Question that could be of wide interest; why don't you post it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slight modification of your strategy ought to work:

```
DateObject[{2016, 7, 17, 0, 0}] /. _TimeObject -> TimeObject[{18, 0, 0}]
```

Comment: (It works on my *gedanken Mathematica*, but I would love for somebody to confirm with their installation.)

Comment: Yes, it works, and you have an impressive mind to pull that off as consistently as you do.  I am openly envious. :^)

Comment: Oh, I had to modify the TimeObject... sound logical on hindsight, thanks, it worked straigt away!

Comment: @PHPirate: "`DateObject[{y, m, d, h, m, s}]` is canonicalized to `DateObject[{y, m, d}, TimeObject[{h, m, s}]]`, where values of `m`, `d`, `h`, `m`, `s` outside their normal ranges are appropriately reduced." This is exploited in the solution given above.

Comment: @J.M. I noticed that in the documentation after your answer, and had noticed earlier that `h=3.5` also worked fine, which was cool to use.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, on the flip side, the installation takes a whole **lot** of time, sometimes interspersed with crashes and hangs. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This should change the Hour to 18:

```
do = DateObject[{2016, 7, 17, 0, 0}]

DateObject[do, {18, 0, 0}]
```

This slightly abridged syntax works as well:

```
DateObject[do, {18}]
```